# CALayer mask does update on device rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, calayer

I have a `CAShapeLayer` subclass that creates a hexagon as a path from it's bounds.  I have another `CALayer` and add an image as the CALayer's `content` and then I set the CALayer's `mask` property to the hexagon layer.  When I add this as a sublayer of my viewController's view the image displays correctly (clipped as a hexagon).

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    MBFHexLayer *hex = [MBFHexLayer hexLayer]; 
    hex.orientation = MBFHexOrientationPointyTopped; 
    hex.frame = self.view.bounds;

    _hexTile = [CALayer layer];
    _hexTile.frame = self.view.bounds;
    _hexTile.mask = hex;
    _hexTile.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"grass.jpg"].CGImage;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_hexTile]; 
}
```

In the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` I set the bounds of the image layer to the bounds of the view and I have overridden `layoutSublayers` in my hexagon mask layer to recompute the path.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    NSLog(@"View Bounds:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
    _hexTile.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [_hexTile setNeedsLayout];
    [_hexTile layoutSublayers];
}
```

CAShapeLayer:

```
-(void)layoutSublayers {

    [self recalcGeometry];
    self.path = [self layerPath].CGPath;
}
```

When I rotate the display the `layoutSublayers` method is not called on my hexagon mask layer and the image is no longer clipped correctly in the view.

I am confused as to what the correct update chain is and any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this Method:

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)  fromInterfaceOrientation {
 //relayout 
  }
```

Comment: This method is deprecated in iOS 8. Besides, it is still not valid to `MVC`. Handling with this may seem to easier at first, but will be harder to fix later.

Comment: Where you get this information? I used this method 2 weeks ago in an iOS 8 app, which is now in the apple store. Normally is written in the Documentation when a method is deprecated, i used it in a swift app but, there were no comment that the method is deprecated :O

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: Besides the documentation, you wrote that you've submitted the app which is using this deprecated method. Using deprecated methods won't make your app rejected. It is written in the documentation, but you must dig to find this information. The language doesn't matter in case of deprecated flags in documentation. Anyway I recommend agains using this method and the successor. `MVC` is most important pattern in iOS and devs should stick to it, as it's one of code quality measures. Layout is a task of view not the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations  :) I would they i'm quite new to Ios development, i know mvc from Java development. Do you have some good advices for iOS patterns like mvc and so on ? like a tutorial site ? thanks :)

Comment: Glad to help :) I'd recommend this page http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns for the beginning. It really quite depends whether you design in code or in Interface Builder. I do it via code (storyboards = no view inheritance, total fail) and each controller must have custom self.view. This also binds to use at least MVC or MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should subclass your view, as it's not `MVC` approach to implement layers in the controller.
2. You you call `layoutSublayers` you should also call `super`.
3. When you subclass your view and implement the layer there, keep a reference to it and in method `layoutSublayersOfLayer:` you should call `setFrame:`

You may check similar approach here: https://github.com/natalia-osa/NORosettaView/blob/master/NORosettaView/Classes/Example2View.m

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The layers are in the view controller for testing purposes.  I want to create a custom layer and I guess my question could be more simply defined as how do I get a layer's mask to update when the parent layer's bounds changes.

Comment: @MagicBulletDave Great to hear it :) In such case you may need to force mask recalculation on `layoutSublayersOfLayer` method. You may also set `[self setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRedraw];`.